# Class does not have id chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I need a help!

```
    const annotationLinePlugin = {
     renderAnnotationLine: function(chartInstance, line) {
      let datasetMeta = chartInstance.getDatasetMeta(line.datasetIndex);
      let context = chartInstance.chart.ctx;
      let datasetModel = datasetMeta.data[line.dataIndex]._model;

      const xBarCenter = datasetModel.x
      const barWidth = datasetModel.width;
      const xStart = xBarCenter - (barWidth / 2) - 4;
      const xEnd = xBarCenter + (barWidth / 2) + 4;

      const yAxisID = datasetMeta.yAxisID;
      const yCoordinate = chartInstance.scales[yAxisID].getPixelForValue(line.yCoordinate);

      context.beginPath();
      context.strokeStyle = line.color;
      context.lineWidth = line.width;
      context.moveTo(xStart, yCoordinate);
      context.lineTo(xEnd, yCoordinate);
      context.stroke();


      if (typeof line.label !== typeof undefined) {
          context.textAlign = 'center';
          context.fillStyle = line.color;
          context.fillText(line.label, yCoordinate, xEnd + 7);
      }
  },

  afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart, easing) {
      if (chart.data.datasets.length < 1) {
          return;
      }
      if (chart.config.lines) {
          chart.config.lines.map(line => {
              this.renderAnnotationLine(chart, line);
          });
      }
  }
};

Chart.register(annotationLinePlugin);
```

I get a error in browser : Uncaught Error : class does not have id

[picture with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXB1r.png)

I had chartjs2, i had to migrate to chartjs3.In chartjs2, there were red lines on every chart object, after switching to chaartjs3, these lines were gone, in the record of cases that Chart.plugins.register was replaced by chart.register, I replaced it, but still nothing worked.

There were the lines :
[lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU13z.png)

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Chart.js 2 to 3</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <canvas id="сhart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script src="./chartjs3/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="./chartjs3/chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./chartjs3/chartjs-plugin-annotation.js"></script>
  <script src="./chartjs3/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./chartjs3/chartjs-plugin-annotationLine.js"></script>
  
  
  <script src="./chartjs3/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>
  <script src="./chartjs3/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./chartjs3/hammer.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
   const ctx = document.getElementById("сhart").getContext("2d"); 
  const options = {
      type: "bar",
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      title: { display: false },
      tooltips: {
        mode: "index",
        intersect: true,
        filter: (tooltipItem, chartData) => {
          return (
            !chartData.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].hideFromTooltip &&
            (chartData.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].yAxisID == "R" ||
              tooltipItem.yLabel > 0)
          );
        },
        callbacks: {
          label: function (tooltipItem, chartData) {
            return (
              chartData.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label +
              ": " +
              tooltipItem.yLabel.round(0)
            );
          },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        duration: 500,
        easing: "linear",
      },
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          display: function (context) {
            const axisMax = context.chart.scales["L"]
              ? context.chart.scales["L"].max
              : 0;
            const datasetLabelsSettings =
              context.chart.data.datasets[context.datasetIndex].datalabels;
            const isLabelOutside =
              datasetLabelsSettings &&
              datasetLabelsSettings.anchor === "end" &&
              datasetLabelsSettings.align === "end";

            return (
              context.chart.isDatasetVisible(context.datasetIndex) &&
              report.chartSettings.showDataLabels &&
              ((isLabelOutside &&
                context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] > 0) ||
                context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] >
                  axisMax * HIDE_DATALABELS_Y_LEVEL) &&
              context.dataset.type !== "line"
            );
          },
          formatter: (x) => {
            return (x || 0).round(0);
          },
        },
      },
      legend: {
        display: true,
        onClick: function (event, legendItem) {
          var index = legendItem.datasetIndex,
            meta = null;
          var tag = chart.data.datasets[index].tag;
          var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(index);

          if (tag || isNumeric(tag)) {
            chart.data.datasets
              .filter((x) => x.tag == tag)
              .forEach((item) => {
                item.hidden = item.forcedHidden || !item.hidden;
              });
          } else {
            meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !meta.hidden : null;
          }
          chart.update();
        },
         position: "top",
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true,
          filter: function (legendItem, chartData) {
            return (
              chartData.datasets[legendItem.datasetIndex].displayInLegend ||
              chartData.datasets[legendItem.datasetIndex].displayInLegend ==
                undefined
            );
            return false;
          },
        },
      },
      cales: {
        xAxes: [
          {
            stacked: true,
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: "Период",
            },
          },
        ],
        yAxes: [
          {
            id: "L",
            type: "linear",
            position: "left",
            stacked: true,
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: "Трудозатраты, чел-мес",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      lines: [
          5553, 5454, 5399, 5290, 5260, 4927, 4565, 4649, 5324, 5624, 5710, 5766,
          5827, 5829, 5831, 5832, 5833, 5835, 5835, 5836, 5836, 5836, 5837, 583,
        ].map((x, i) => {
          return {
            datasetIndex: 0,
            dataIndex: i,
            yCoordinate: x,
            color: "salmon",
            width: 3,
          };
        
      }),
       data: {
        labels: [
          "2022-01",
          "2022-02",
          "2022-03",
          "2022-04",
          "2022-05",
          "2022-06",
          "2022-07",
          "2022-08",
          "2022-09",
          "2022-10",
          "2022-11",
          "2022-12",
          "2023-01",
          "2023-02",
          "2023-03",
          "2023-04",
          "2024-05",
          "2023-06",
          "2023-07",
          "2023-08",
          "2023-09",
          "2023-10",
          "2023-11",
          "2023-12",
        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "ОПИ (ресурсный профиль)",
            findId: "ОПИ",
            tag: "ОПИ",
            type: "bar",
            borderWidth: 1,
            stack: "cnt",
            groupType: "cnt",
            backgroundColor: "#2196f3",
            fill: false,
            pointStyle: "rect",
            detailMode: "point",
            data: [
              5356, 5802, 6105, 6258, 6524, 6690, 6697, 7348, 6578, 5742, 4626,
              3678, 4809, 6038, 5891, 4526, 3637, 3601, 3471, 3618, 3548, 3428,
              3330, 3448, 5031,
            ],
            displayInLegend: false,
            datalabels: {
              anchor: "end",
              align: "end",
              offset: 0,
              color: function (context) {
                return "#2196f3";
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        
      },
    };
    const сhart = new Chart(ctx, options);


  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The plugin needs to have an unique id.

You could add an id (see following example):

```
 const annotationLinePlugin = {
   id: 'annotationLine',
   ....  
 }
```

Be also aware the afterDatasetsDraw hook has got a different signature (arguments).
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/Plugin.html#afterdatasetsdraw